# Unable to run sh steps inside docker agent: script.sh Not Found

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When trying to run the following declarative pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker 'alpine' }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh('printenv')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Agent Setup)
[Pipeline] sh
[TmpTest] Running shell script
+ docker pull alpine
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
Digest: sha256:1072e499f3f655a032e88542330cf75b02e7bdf673278f701d7ba61629ee3ebe
Status: Image is up to date for alpine:latest
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] sh
[TmpTest] Running shell script
+ docker inspect -f . alpine
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 107:113 -w /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TmpTest -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TmpTest:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TmpTest:rw,z -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TmpTest@tmp:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TmpTest@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** --entrypoint cat alpine
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Provision Server)
[Pipeline] sh
[TmpTest] Running shell script
sh: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TmpTest@tmp/durable-1abfbc69/script.sh: not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 db551b51404ba6305f68f9086320634eeea3d515be134e5e55b51c3c9f1eb568
$ docker rm -f db551b51404ba6305f68f9086320634eeea3d515be134e5e55b51c3c9f1eb568
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

When monitoring the pipelines `@tmp` directory whilst its running I can see `script.sh` created for a short period. I am unable to tell if it has been created, or already deleted, when the pipeline tries to execute it in the running container.

### some system details

Jenkins running as a single node system which has docker installed.

```
Jenkins v2.60.1
(all plugins fully updated)

docker --version
Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87
```

Comment: I'm seeing very similar behaviour with a near-identical system (though I'm running Jenkins in Docker). In my case my script runs `checkout scm`, then inside a new docker container I `ls` and see the files, then `sh "script.sh"` but get "not found".

Comment: For what it's worth I also see this issue when using a scripted pipeline and the `withDockerContainer` step.

Comment: I think I found a workaround: `sh 'sh ./gradlew...'`

Answer (score 2):

Have the same setup (single Jenkins 2.73.1 host on an EC2 instance, not inside a container, with Docker 17.09.0-ce) and the same behavior, with both declarative and scripted pipeline.
It tries to run the script on the host itself if you specify

```
sh 'sh ./yourscript.sh'
```

or

```
sh './yourscript.sh'
```

instead of `sh 'script.sh'`

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Has this been reported in the Jenkins CI issue tracker?